# jQuery-brackets: How to save to python/sqlite3?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do a tournament bracket for my webapp and so far I am using jQuery-brackets lib: http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/

Im totally unfamiliar with javascript though I couldnt find anything like jquery-bracket in python world.

I'm using the demo code for Save functionality:

```
var saveData = {
  teams: [
    ["Team 1", "Team 2"],
    ["Team 3", null],
    ["Team 4", null],
    ["Team 5", null]
  ],
  results: [
      [
        [[1, 0], [null, null], [null, null], [null, null]],
        [[null, null], [1, 4]],
        [[null, null], [null, null]]
      ]
  ]
};
 
/* Called whenever bracket is modified
 *
 * data:     changed bracket object in format given to init
 * userData: optional data given when bracket is created.
 */
function saveFn(data, userData) {
  var json = jQuery.toJSON(data)
  $('#saveOutput').text('POST '+userData+' '+json)
  /* You probably want to do something like this
  jQuery.ajax("rest/"+userData, {contentType: 'application/json',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                type: 'post',
                                data: json})
  */
}
 
$(function() {
    var container = $('div#save .demo')
    container.bracket({
      init: saveData,
      save: saveFn,
      userData: "http://myapi"})
 
    /* You can also inquiry the current data */
    var data = container.bracket('data')
    $('#dataOutput').text(jQuery.toJSON(data))
  })
```

I would like to pass the saveData as POST to python to write it to my sqlite3 db. But I just fail at even understand the few lines of js code.

1. His note says: 'Called whenever bracket is modified.' I guess he means whenever something is edited in the webapp bracket, the function saveFn(data, userData) gets called. Correct? so I tried:

JS:

```
function saveFn(data, userData) {
      var json = jQuery.toJSON(data)
      $('#saveOutput').text('POST '+userData+' '+json)
      $.post( "/update", {
        javascript_data: data 
        });
```

py:

```
@app.route('/update',methods=["POST","GET"])
def update():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form['javascript_data']
        print(data)
    return jsonify('Successfully called')
```

But nothing happens, feels like I misunderstand what is called whenever bracket changes. I think once I get data to python whenever bracket data is changed in the webapp I can go on by myself in py and sqlite.

2. Dev also mentions:

> Additional parameters. Requires save callback to be given.

```
disableToolbar: boolean hides the toolbar that allows resizing the bracket and changing its type
disableTeamEdit: boolean disallows editing teams, allows still editing scores. You must ALSO disable the toolbar (as incresing bracket size would add BYE teams, thus "editing teams")
```

I would like to add this but I dont know where to put the parameter to disable toolbar and I also dont understand what it means to ' Requires save callback to be given.'

Help is much appreciated, I am stuck on this for a few days, digging through several js tutorials, tried-and-errored many times and feel like I'm missing some very important thing or looking at the wrong code to customize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really started to hate JS/JSON/jQuery as a noob but then I found the problem: In developer tools of chrome I got the info that jQuery.toJSON() was not found! Of course, nothing else happens after! replace it with JSON.stringify() Also, to disable toolbar (q2) you simply put 'disableToolbar: true,' next to where i.e. 'init: saveData' is